# Multipart form script works perfectly in PowerShell but not in PowerShell core

Tags: powershell-core

The following code works perfectly in PowerShell on a Windows Server

```
$user = "XXXXX"
$pass = "XXXXX"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $pass)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization',('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add('Accept','application/json')

#$FilePath = 'C:\Upload\User Entitlement Export.csv';
$FilePath = '/Users/XXXXXX/Downloads/User Entitlement Export.csv';

$URL = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXX.com/sys_import.do?sysparm_transform_after_load=true&sysparm_import_set_tablename=u_alm_entitlement_user';

$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath);
$fileEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetString($fileBytes);
$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
#$boundary = 'another cool boundary';
$LF = "`r`n";

$bodyLines = (
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"User Entitlement Export.csv`"",
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF",
    $fileEnc,
    "--$boundary--$LF"
) -join $LF

Write-Host $bodyLines;

Invoke-RestMethod -Proxy http://XXXXXXX:8080 -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials -Uri $URL -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines -Headers $headers
```

But when I run in PowerShell core on a Mac I receive the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The format of value 'multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8;boundary="d0d0dccd-698c-48b8-8770-6bcc7d29f609"' is invalid.
At /Users/laurensbrand/Downloads/uploadCSV.ps1:33 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], FormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Any idea what is wrong here? Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't test this myself but after a little looking it appears Strict Header validation is enabled by default in Core and has affected the web commandlets.

Try using the switch `-SkipHeaderValidation` with the Core version.

More info here:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6002#issuecomment-359987432
https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/11/powershell-core-web-cmdlets-in-depth.html#L08

Comment: I clearly did not read this article correctly when I googled it myself. Thank you for pointing it out. Unfortunately it there seems to be an issue(s) with -SkipHeaderValidation either not working at all or not in every case. Have to keep trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to install powershell-6.1.0-preview.4-osx-x64. I was using powershell-6.0.3-osx-x64.